# Find credit card by type and expiration date

Tags: node.js, braintree

According to [this](https://www.braintreepayments.com/features/account-updater) *"Account Updater only works with Visa and Mastercard"*

So I want to find customers whose cards are going to expire in the next month and are from a different type than Visa or Mastercard.

In the [docs](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/search/node) I see I can filter by expiration date, but nothing about [cardType](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/response/credit-card/node#card_type) (it mentions cardholderName)

```
var stream = gateway.customer.search(function (search) {
  search.creditCardExpirationDate().is("12/13");
});
```

Is there a way I can filter this in the api request or should I need to get all results and filter out Visa and Mastercard customers?

Thanks.

Comment: As stated here you can't look for credit card type in the customer.search method. https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/request/customer/search/node

Comment: @Michelem thanks but I already saw those docs, that link is referenced in the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

Both you and @michelem are correct: the current api doesn't expose a method for filtering customers based on whether they contain a specific type of card. Your approach of filtering the results based on the Payment method is the best approach.